# Хранение деревьев в БД

Tags: база-данных

Нужно в БД хранить два идентичных по структуре дерева. В каждом дереве в конечных листьях есть набор атрибутов (для каждого дерева свой набор). Между узлами этих двух деревьев могут быть установлены горизонтальные связи.

Вопрос - деревья лучше хранить в разных таблицах

1. Tree1

   - id
   - owner_id
   - name
   - is_leaf
2. Tree1LeafAttributes

   - leaf_id (primary)
   - tree1_attr1
   - tree1_attr2
   - ...............
3. Tree2

   - id
   - owner_id
   - name
   - is_leaf
4. Tree2LeafAttributes

   - leaf_id (primary)
   - tree2_attr1
   - tree2_attr2
   - ...............
5. Links

   - tree1_node
   - tree2_node

Или оба дерева хранить в одной таблице?

1. Trees

   - id
   - owner_id
   - name
   - tree_type
   - is_leaf
2. Tree1LeafAttributes

   - leaf_id (primary)
   - tree1_attr1
   - tree1_attr2
   - ...............
3. Tree2LeafAttributes

   - leaf_id (primary)
   - tree2_attr1
   - tree2_attr2
   - ...............
4. Links

   - tree1_node
   - tree2_node

Плюсы первого варианта: на порядок проще валидация. Нельзя прицепить ссылку не на то дерево

Плюсы второго - нет дублирования структуры

Comment: Все таки зависит от подобия этих деревьев в реальной жизни. По самой структуре деревьев не ясно зачем нужны is_leaf. И на счет атрибутов листьев по текущей структуре выходит, что у одного листа может быть несколько наборов атрибутов...

Comment: @Mike is_leaf нужен, чтобы атрибуты цеплять только на них. Грубо говоря есть файлы, есть папки. У папки есть только имя, у файла есть еще куча атрибутов. is_leaf нужен, чтобы атрибуты не прицепить к узлу. Немного подправил структуру и убрал Attribute.id

Comment: Первый вариант мне больше нравится. Во втором, помимо сложности контроля внешних ссылок еще есть потенциальная возможность, что tree_type у ветви и ее листа будут отличаться.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо. Ну тогда будем от него плясать

Comment: Во втором случае с одной таблицей можно добавить в foreign key tree_type, (или добавить колонку owner_type и её включить в foreign key (owner_id, owner_type) => (id, tree_type)),  понаствить ограничений проверок и таким нехитрым образом избавится от недостатков.

Comment: @Sergey Двойной внешний ключ идея интересная и красивая. Позволяет убрать ряд проверок